# Javascript regex, correct match on the online test sites, but wrong in the code

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs

I have regex for matching time formats in 24 hours
accepted formats are : 1:00, 01:00, 100, 0100, and so on to 23 hours

But also, I have special case - I need availability to accept 1:00*, 01:00* or 100* for DST transition hours

so it's basically concatenation of two regex expressions

This is the regex string
`^(0?1:?[0-5][0-9]\*)|((0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9]):?[0-5][0-9])$`

on https://regex101.com/, http://www.regexplanet.com/:

```
    1:00 - true
    1:00* - true
    1:00& - false
    2:00 - true
```

in the code:

```
    var r = new RegExp('^(0?1:?[0-5][0-9]\*)|((0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9]):?[0-5][0-9])$');
    var b1 = r.test("1:00"); // true
    var b2 = r.test("1:00*"); // true 
    var b3 = r.test("1:00&"); // true - wrong
    var b4 = r.test("1:00#"); // true - wrong
```

so it returns false matches for any symbol after time string

I changed that with ^ and $ after each sub-expression

`^(0?1:?[0-5][0-9]\*)$|^((0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9]):?[0-5][0-9])$`

online test:

```
    1:00 - true
    1:00* - true
    1:00& - false
    2:00 - true
```

in the code:

```
    var r = new RegExp('^(0?1:?[0-5][0-9]\*)$|^((0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9]):?[0-5][0-9])$');
    var b1 = r.test("1:00"); // true
    var b2 = r.test("1:00*"); // false - wrong
    var b3 = r.test("1:00&"); // false
    var b4 = r.test("1:00#"); // false
```

So in both cases online test works as it should be, but in the code it is not.
What can be the problem?

I cannot use '/^(0?1:?[0-5][0-9]*)$/' form, because Extjs 4.2.3 doesnt accept such form for text field validation. I use it for form field validation in the construction like this:

```
    regex: new RegExp('^(0?1:?[0-5][0-9]\*)$|((0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9]):?[0-5][0-9])$'),
    regexText: 'Not a valid time. Accepted formats: HMM, H:MM, HHMM, HH:MM, 1:MM*, 01:MM*, 1MM*'
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to escape the `*` two times, once for the string, once for the regexp:

```
var r = new RegExp('^(0?1:?[0-5][0-9]\\*)|((0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9]):?[0-5][0-9])$');
```

or you can say this:

```
var r = /^(0?1:?[0-5][0-9]\*)|((0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9]):?[0-5][0-9])$/
```

Just try these in console to understand:

```
var str = '\*';
console.log(str); // *

var r = new RegExp('[0-9]\*');
console.log(r); // /[0-9]*/

var str = '\\*';
console.log(str); // \*

var r = new RegExp('[0-9]\\*');
console.log(r); // /[0-9]\*/
```